# Facebook cookie access through PHP codeigniter

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, codeigniter, cookies

I want to get the email address of a user when he visits my site by checking if he currently has a facebook session going on in the browser. If he has then is there a way I can extract his email address from the facebook cookie and store it in my website's database for future reference.

Please note that I don't want to create a Facebook App just want to extract the email address of the user from their cookie. I'll create a Facebook login later but as of now I just want to keep track of any visitor as well if possible for example by the above scenario.

I couldn't find it in their developer documentation hence I'm asking the forum. I'm using Codeigniter for PHP srcipting on my website and its basically a E-commerce website.

Any javascript or Jquery solutions will work as well!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. This is not possible. If anybody could get everybody's email without asking then people would be even more angry at Facebook.

Comment: I know that would be a big intrusion of privacy, but I just wanted to check for a possibility if he already has a FB session on the browser and is simultaneously browsing my website as well. I always knew the answer but its just good to ask sometimes to be sure. Thanks anyway. Have a great Sunday